# Format address based on abbreviation list using Google Apps Script/formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of addresses that I want to format, I am using some samples here:

```
Simple Addresses:

    30 LOCUST AVENUE
    11 QUINE STREET
    1 Avenue A
    737-41 RAMSEY AVENUE STRAVEN
    731 RAMSEY AVE STRAVENUE
    100 HOFFMAN PL THROUGHWAY
```

I want these address to be compared with abbreviation list:

```
Abbreviation List:

    AVENUE     -> AVE
    STREET     -> ST
    STRAVEN    -> STR
    THROUGHWAY -> TRWY
    STRAVENUE  -> STR
```

And the **formatted Address** will be:

```
30 LOCUST AVE
11 QUINE STR
1 Ave A
737-41 RAMSEY AVE STR
731 RAMSEY AVE STR
100 HOFFMAN PL TRWY
```

Due to my beginner skills I am not able to find out any solution. Is there any formula or script that can compare the address with the abbreviation list and format the addresses if any word(s) from address is found in abbreviation list? Please let me know if any question, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, `11 QUINE STREET` is converted to `11 QUINE STR`. But, it seems that you want to use `STREET -> ST`. So, I guessed that you might have miscopied your sample output situation. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this script, it supposes that your sample input values are put into the cells "A1:A". Please be careful about this.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // This is from your question.
  const obj = { "AVENUE": "AVE", "STREET": "ST", "STRAVEN": "STR", "THROUGHWAY": "TRWY", "STRAVENUE": "STR" };

  const ar = Object.entries(obj);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet50");
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => {
    let temp = a.split(" ");
    ar.forEach(([from, to]) => temp = temp.map(t => t.toLowerCase() == from.toLocaleLowerCase() ? to : t));
    return [temp.join(" ")];
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run with your sample input values, the following result is obtained.

  ```
  30 LOCUST AVE
  11 QUINE ST
  1 AVE A
  737-41 RAMSEY AVE STR
  731 RAMSEY AVE STR
  100 HOFFMAN PL TRWY
  ```
- When you want to use this script as a custom function, please use the following script. In this case, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE(A1:A)` into a cell. By this, the converted values are returned.

  ```js
  function SAMPLE(values) {
    const obj = { "AVENUE": "AVE", "STREET": "ST", "STRAVEN": "STR", "THROUGHWAY": "TRWY", "STRAVENUE": "STR" };

    const ar = Object.entries(obj);
    return values.map(([a]) => {
      let temp = a.split(" ");
      ar.forEach(([from, to]) => temp = temp.map(t => t.toLowerCase() == from.toLocaleLowerCase() ? to : t));
      return [temp.join(" ")];
    });
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> In this line const obj = { "AVENUE": "AVE".....}, can we use generic range like A1:A500 (AVENUE,STREET...), B1:B500(AVE,ST...), because I have long list (500) of abbreviations and it is not ideal to copy each abbreviation into obj

> Here is the sample sheet for your review:

When your provided Spreadsheet is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

This script was modified the above script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("AbbreviationsList");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sample Data");
  const ar = sheet1.getRange("A2:B" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const range = sheet2.getRange("A2:A" + sheet2.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => {
    let temp = a.split(" ");
    ar.forEach(([from, to]) => temp = temp.map(t => t.toLowerCase() == from.toLocaleLowerCase() ? to : t));
    return [temp.join(" ")];
  });
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

or, I think that the process cost of following modification might be lower than that of the above one.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("AbbreviationsList");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sample Data");
  const obj = new Map(sheet1.getRange("A2:B" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues().map(([a, b]) => [a.toLocaleLowerCase(), b]));
  const range = sheet2.getRange("A2:A" + sheet2.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [a.split(" ").map(t => obj.get(t.toLowerCase()) || t).join(" ")]);
  range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this case, the converted values are put into column "B" of "Sample Data" sheet.
- If you want to overwrite, please modify `range.offset(0, 1).setValues(values)` to `range.setValues(values)`.
- In this case, if you want to use this script as a custom function, you can use the following script. In this case, when you want to use this script with your provided Spreadsheet, please put a custom function of `=SAMPLE('AbbreviationsList'!A2:B, 'Sample Data'!A2:A)` into a cell. By this, the converted values are returned.

  ```js
  function SAMPLE(values1, values2) {
    const obj = new Map(values1.map(([a, b]) => [a.toLocaleLowerCase(), b]));
    return values2.map(([a]) => [a.split(" ").map(t => obj.get(t.toLowerCase()) || t).join(" ")]);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In this line `const obj = { "AVENUE": "AVE".....}`, can we use generic range like A1:A500 (AVENUE,STREET...), B1:B500(AVE,ST...), because I have long list (500) of abbreviations and it is not ideal to copy each abbreviation into obj

Comment: Here is the sample sheet for your review: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7lkcHplr2uADbDbjpoOJF1ShcSy422aSelkJeGFLnI/edit?usp=sharing`

Comment: @EagleEye Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more sample script for your provided Spreadsheet. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for detailed solutions, it works as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula too, considering your ranges A:A and B:B as you suggested in comments:

```
=REDUCE(C1,A1:A,LAMBDA(addr,rep,IF(rep="",addr,REGEXREPLACE(addr,"\b"&rep&"\b",OFFSET(rep,0,1)))))
```

If you have more addresses let's say in column C you could wrap it in BYROW:

```
=BYROW(C:C,LAMBDA(ad,IF(and="","",REDUCE(ad,A1:A,LAMBDA(addr,rep,IF(rep="",addr,REGEXREPLACE(addr,"\b"&rep&"\b",OFFSET(rep,0,1))))))))
```

[image]

If you want it to be case insensitive change `"\b"&rep&"\b"` with `"\b(?i)"&rep&"\b"`

Comment: Thank you, but all addresses should not be in one cell, they should one address per row

Comment: I tried your `=BYROW(C1:C500)` formula version,  it shows error saying `Calculation limit is reached`